# Invoke-RestMethod with PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, post

I am trying to post data to a URL using PowerShells `Invoke-RestMethod` however I constantly keep getting this message:

> ```
> + $response.RawContent​
> +                     ~
> Unexpected token '​' in expression or statement.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
> ```

Am I missing an escape of a string literal somewhere or malformed quote mark?

```
$user = "username"
$pass = "password"


$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $pass)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization',('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add('Accept','application/json')
$headers.Add('Content-Type','application/json')

$uri = "http://myurl.com"

$params = @{
message = "hello world"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $headers -Uri $uri -Body $params

$response.RawContent​
```

Comment: `-Method` parameter is present twice. Is this correct? What is `$method`? Please consider [edit]ing your question and sharing a [mcve].

Comment: $method use to be $method = "post" ; however, in trying to figure out where my error was i moved the method into the response directly. I have edited the code. Still get the same unexpected token error...

Answer (score 0):

Removed $response.RawContent and it works. Changed it to echo $response to see output.